# Python remove words in every string from list

Tags: python, list, split, slice

So I have a list that has a strings in the form of a sentence as each element, like this

```
a = ["This is a sentence with some words.", "And this is a sentence as well.", "Also this right here is a sentence."]
```

What I want to do with this list is to only keep the third and fourth word of each string, so in the end I want a list like

```
b = ["a sentence", "is a", "right here"]
```

The first thing to do I presume is to split the list after spaces, so something like

```
for x in a:
    x.split()
```

However I'm a bit confused on how to continue. The above loop should produce basically one list per sentence where every word is an own element. I thought about doing this

```
e = []
for x in a:
    x.split()
    a = x[0:2]
    a = x[2:]
    e.append(a)
```

but instead of removing words it removes characters and I get the following output

```
['is is a sentence with some words.', 'd this is a sentence as well.', 'so this right here is a sentence.']
```

I'm not sure why it produces this behavior. I have been sitting at this for a while now and probably missed something really stupid, so I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: The result of `x.split()` is not stored any way and the effect is does not take place in x as you might think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `x.split()`, the output does not take effect on `x` itself, it results in a list of strings, since `string`s are not mutable:

`lst = s.split()`,

Then just join your desired items:

`e.append(' '.join(lst[2:4]))`

Comment: @Brian no pblm ;)

Answer (score 4):

Nothing can modify a string, they are immutable. You can only derive data from it. As others have said, you need to store the value of `.split()`.

Lists are mutable but slicing them also does not modify them in place, it creates a new sublist which you need to store somewhere. Overall this can be done like so:

```
e = [' '.join(x.split()[2:4]) for x in a]
```

The whole thing is a list comprehension in case you're not familiar. `.join()` converts the sublist back into a string.

Comment: @AChampion thanks, hadn't realised they wanted strings in the end.

Comment: This code may answer the question, but your answer would be improved with a bit of explanation.

Comment: Not sure that's a good reason to vote it down... compensating.

Comment: @vascowhite better?

Comment: That seems to be the most pythonic solution to my problem, a bit over my skill level but good to know about, thanks!

Comment: @Brian there's not much to know. A basic list comprehension is just a matter of replacing code of the form `e = []; for x in y: e.append(f(x))` with `[f(x) for x in y]`. Iron Fist's answer is in the first form, this answer is the same but with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable. `x.split()` returns a list of strings, but does not modify x. However you do not capture that return value, so it is lost.